# How to display array in an array in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an API call that returns its result as an array in an array. Each array has a array of card transactions that should be displayed.

The console logged result I have

```
Array [
  Object {
    "data": Array [
     
      Object {
       "id": 1035988,
        "amount": 1.5,
        "amount_confirmed": 0,
        ...
      },
      Object {
        "id": 1011990,
        "amount": 5,
        "amount_confirmed": 0,
       ...
      },
    ],
    "message": "Card transactions fetched successfully",
    "status": "success",
  },
  Object {
    "data": Array [
    
      Object {
        "id": 1011923,
        "amount": 10,
        "amount_confirmed": 0,
        ...
      },
      Object {
        "id": 10119234,
        "amount": 1.5,
        "amount_confirmed": 0,
      ...
      },
     
    ],
    "message": "Card transactions fetched successfully",
    "status": "success",
  },
]
```

I am at lost here how to display it.
I have tried this and a few others but nothing is displayed.

```
 <nb-list-item v-for="cardTransactions in card_transactions" v-bind:key="cardTransactions.data.id">
<!--content-->
</nb-list-item>
```

Comment: what do you want to display from the array?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<nb-list-item v-for="cardTransactions in card_transactions" :key="cardTransactions.data.id">
  <template v-if="cardTransactions.data && cardTransactions.data.length > 0">
    <div v-for="(transaction, i) in cardTransactions.data" :key="cardTransactions.data.id + '-transaction-' + i">
      <p>
        <strong v-text="cardTransactions.message" />
        <div>
          {{transaction}}
        </div>
      </p>
    </div>
  </template>
</nb-list-item>
```